# Array Fails To Use String Parameter

Tags: php, ajax, arrays, variables

I've spent the last 20 minutes trying to figure out why, when using AJAX, my string value is failing to work.

I have a form that, when submitted, sends the data to `evo.php` with a `$_GET` value `id` of say `"01"`.

The first thing I do is assign the `$_GET` value to a local variable `$id` by means of `$id = $_GET['id'];` Nothing wrong with that. My code goes on to declare an array:

```
$evo = array(
    "01" => "Milk",
    "02" => "Fruit",
    "03" => "Other"
);
```

Now if I `echo $id;` I will get the exact response of `"01"`. However, if I attempt to `echo $evo[$id];` I get the response: `Undefined index: "01"`. This would make sense, if `echo $evo["01"];` didn't give me the response `"Milk"`.

I don't understand how by calling `$id` within `$evo[]` throws me an error?
I have tried changing the values to integers with the exact same results.

The only reason I've not included AJAX is because I'm not returning anything at the moment, just trying to get the values from `$evo[]` using the `$id`.

Comment: I can get it to work here using exactly the same code you are using (http://d.pr/n/2mO3). Are you sure `$id` contains exactly the `"01"` string? Call `var_dump` passing it as a parameter and show the output here please.

Comment: It works for me check here [PHP fiddle](http://www.phpfiddle.org/main/code/rcf-zgb) , double check `$evo`

Comment: You said that when you `echo $id`, you get the exact response of `"01"`, Could it be possible that you are also passing the quotes as well as 01?

Answer (score 0):

The variable was being passed over as a string, as such `$id` was actually `""01""`. I'm pretty sure I `var_dump()`'d just about everything else. Thank you!